My scrollbar glitches as new chat is streamed from LLM in Streamlit
I am creating a Streamlit chat application that helps communicate with a model similar to ChatGPT. I am trying to stream the response from the LLM but whenever the response is streamed, the chat glitches and jerks to the top sometimes. I noticed that this usually happens when I am using my Linux system rather than my Windows. Does anybody have any advice on what to do? Much appreciated.
def general_chat(user_input):

    response_placeholder = st.empty()

    streamed_response = ""
    try:
        blocked_topics = "\n".join([f"Do not answer any questions about: {keyword}" for keyword in key_data])

        history_context = "\n".join(f"{chat['role']}: {chat['message']}" for chat in st.session_state.chat_history)

        prompt_input = (
            f"{history_context}\n"
            f"Instructions:\n"
            f"{blocked_topics}\n"  # Explicitly define what is off-limits
            f"User: {user_input}\n"
            f"Assistant:"
        )

        for chunk in llm.stream(prompt_input):  # Adjust to your LLM's streaming API
            streamed_response += chunk
            response_placeholder.write(streamed_response)
            time.sleep(0.1)

        st.session_state.chat_history.append({"role": "assistant", "message": streamed_response.strip()})
    except Exception as e:
        st.session_state.chat_history.append({"role": "assistant", "message": "Server busy. Please try again later."})
        logger.info(str(e))

The above is the function which helps get the response from the LLM.
def chat_page():
        """Render the chat page."""
        st.markdown(
            """
<style>
            .st-emotion-cache-1c7y2kd {
                flex-direction: row-reverse;
                text-align: right;
            }
</style>
        """,
            unsafe_allow_html=True,
        )
        # hide_streamlit_toolbar()
        col1, col2 = st.columns([6, 2])
        with col1:
            st.subheader('ThinkBot')
            st.write('Welcome to ThinkBot! I am an AI Chatbot. Choose "General" for general inquiries or '
                     'select a specific project for project-related questions.')


        # Initialize chat history in session state if not present
        if 'chat_history' not in st.session_state:
            st.session_state.chat_history = []
            st.session_state.chat_history.append({"role": "assistant", "message": "How can I help you?"})
        # Display chat history
        # Display chat history with alignment
        bot_image = image_to_base64("images/chat_profile-bot.png")
        me_image = image_to_base64("images/chat_profile-me.png")
        for idx, chat in enumerate(st.session_state.chat_history):
            message_key = f"{chat['role']}_{idx}"  # Unique key based on role and index
            if chat["role"] == "user":
                # Use st.chat_message for user message
                with st.chat_message("user",avatar="images/chat_profile-me.png"):
                    st.write(chat['message'])
            else:
                # Use st.chat_message for bot message
                with st.chat_message("assistant", avatar="images/chat_profile-bot.png"):
                    st.write(chat['message'])
        # Collect user input
        if user_input := st.chat_input(placeholder="Your Message"):
            st.session_state.chat_history.append({"role": "user", "message": user_input})
            st.session_state.process_input = True
            st.rerun()
        # Check if we need to process the input
        if st.session_state.get("process_input"):
            with st.spinner('Processing...'):
                general_chat(st.session_state.chat_history[-1]["message"])
                st.session_state.process_input = False
                st.rerun()

The function chat_page() helps create the page.
A few methods I have already tried are:

streamlit_chat

Stopping automatic scrolling using
.stAppScrollToBottomContainer {
overflow-anchor: none !important;
}


Nothing has worked so far.

You have over-complicated this stuff - just follow the official streamlit docs to build conversational apps for an intro to building chat UIs using streamlit.
Meanwhile, I refactored your code and made it work with ollama as follows:
import streamlit as st
from ollama import chat

def ollama_generator(prompt_input):
    stream = chat(
        model="llama3.2",
        messages=[{'role': 'user', 'content': prompt_input}],
        stream=True,
    )
    for chunk in stream:
        yield chunk['message']['content']

def general_chat(user_input):
    try:
        key_data = ["politics", "religion", "violence"]
        blocked_topics = "\n".join([f"Do not answer any questions about: {keyword}" for keyword in key_data])
        history_context = "\n".join(f"{chat['role']}: {chat['content']}" for chat in st.session_state.chat_history)
        prompt_input = (
            f"{history_context}\n"
            f"Instructions:\n"
            f"{blocked_topics}\n"
            f"User: {user_input}\n"
            f"Assistant:"
        )

        with st.chat_message("assistant"):
            response = st.write_stream(ollama_generator(prompt_input))

        st.session_state.chat_history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})
    except Exception as e:
        st.session_state.chat_history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": "Server busy. Please try again later."})


def chat_page():
    st.title("ThinkBot")
    st.write("Welcome to ThinkBot! I am an AI Chatbot.")

    if "chat_history" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.chat_history = []
        st.session_state.chat_history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": "How can I help you?"})

    for message in st.session_state.chat_history:
        with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
            st.markdown(message["content"])

    if user_input := st.chat_input(placeholder="Your message"):
        st.session_state.chat_history.append({"role": "user", "content": user_input})

        with st.chat_message("user"):
            st.markdown(user_input)
        
        general_chat(user_input)

def main():
    chat_page()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This should work fine on all the platforms hopefully and now you have a functional chatbot with a streaming typewriter effect.
Note: Please ensure Ollama is running if you want to test this code as is.
